# Get return from gdb exec

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

In `.gdbinit` I call to function

`call open("tmp/test",1)`

Then I got return value

`$15 = 1`

I want to use `$15` to the next operation.

How can I got this var to the `.gdbinit` next line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign the return value to a variable with a name of your choosing:

```
(gdb) call $ret = open("tmp/test", 1)
(gdb) print $ret
-1
```